# Jersey Rest services - is there a way to get restrict and order XMLElements in the response?

Tags: json, rest, genson

I have a REST service that outputs a list of POJO. The response XML/JSON contains all fields annotated with XMLElement. Is there a way to restrict the fields in the response (programmatically on runtime)? Also can I specify the order the fields again on runtime?

POJO:

```
 @XmlRootElement
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
 public class Employee {
    @XmlElement
    @Column(name="Name", length=75) @NotNull @Length(max=75)        
    private String name;   

    @XmlElement
    @Column(name="designation", length=75)       
    private String designation;   

    @XmlElement
    @Column(name="department", length=75)        
    private String department;   
}

@Path("employee")
public class EmployeeRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response emp() {
        return Response.ok(getDetails(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();;
    }

    @Path("xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response emp() {
        GenericEntity<List<Employee>> list = new GenericEntity<List<Employee>>(getDetails()) {};
        return Response.ok(list, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();;
    }

    public List<Employee> getDetails() {
        .....
        return list;
    }
}

My output now is:
JSON:
[{name:Tom,designation:Manager,department:IT},{name:Jim,designation:Clerk,department:IT}]
XML:
<employees>
    <employee>
      <name>Tom</name>
      <designation>Manager</designation>
      <department>IT</department>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Jim</name>
      <designation>Clerk</designation>
      <department>IT</department>
    </employee>
</employees>

Desired output:
JSON:
[{designation:Manager,name:Tom},{designation:Clerk,name:Jim}]
XML:
<employees>
    <employee>
      <designation>Manager</designation>
      <name>Tom</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <designation>Clerk</designation>
      <name>Jim</name>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Fields and the order will be known only when the request is submitted. So annotations like JSONIgnore won't help me. 
How can I do it? I tried Genson. While I can restrict the fields in a JSON response, I couldn't do it for XML response. Also I am not able to order the fields.

Comment: Yes with Genson you can not change the order yet and it is a lib for json not xml.

Comment: Is there any other library or API that I can use?

Comment: you can follow : https://dzone.com/articles/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder

Answer (score 1):

For setting up you custom order you can use :

@XmlType(propOrder={"designation", "name", "department", "abcd"})